How to add shadow to a custom bottom tabbar in .Net Maui on CustomAndroidShellHandler?
I need your help figuring out why I can't get a shadow behind the center button on Android. I have it working in iOS just fine, but it doesn't work.
This is my iOS handler appearance
iOS Image
Android Image
Here is the code in my Android handler itself - can anyone help me figure out how to give a shadow appearance behind the center circle?
public override View? OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup? container, Bundle? savedInstanceState)
{
    var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    if (Context is not null && ShellItem is ArtemisBar { CenterVisible: true } tabBar)
    {
    var rootLayout = new FrameLayout(Context)
    {
        LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent)
    };

    rootLayout.AddView(view);
    const int middleViewSize = 100;
    var middleViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutMargins.WrapContent,
            ViewGroup.LayoutMargins.WrapContent,
            GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal | GravityFlags.Bottom)
    {
        BottomMargin = 40
    };
    var middleView = new Button(Context)
    {
        LayoutParameters = middleViewLayoutParams
    };
    middleView.Click += delegate
    {
        tabBar.CenterCommand?.Execute(null);
    };
    middleView.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        middleView.SetShadowLayer(5,0,-20,Colors.DarkGray.ToPlatform());
    if (tabBar.CenterBackgroundColor is not null)
    {
        var backgroundView = new View(Context)
        {
            LayoutParameters = middleViewLayoutParams
        };
        var backgroundDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
        backgroundDrawable.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
        backgroundDrawable.SetCornerRadius(middleViewSize / 4f);
        backgroundDrawable.SetColor(tabBar.CenterBackgroundColor.ToPlatform(Colors.Green));
        backgroundDrawable.Thickness = 2;
        backgroundView.SetBackground(backgroundDrawable);
        backgroundView.SetElevation(1);
        rootLayout.AddView(backgroundView);
    }
                
    tabBar.CenterIcon?.LoadImage(Application.Current!.MainPage!.Handler!.MauiContext!, result =>
    {
        if (result?.Value is not BitmapDrawable drawable || drawable.Bitmap is null)
        {
            return;
        }
        const int padding = 20;
        middleView.LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        drawable.Bitmap.Width - padding, 
        drawable.Bitmap.Height - padding,
        GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal | GravityFlags.Bottom)
        {
            BottomMargin = middleViewLayoutParams.BottomMargin - (int)(.65 * padding)
        };
        middleView.SetShadowLayer(2,0,0,Colors.LightGray.ToPlatform());
        middleView.SetBackground(drawable);
        middleView.SetShadowLayer(8,0,-100, Colors.DarkGray.ToPlatform());
        middleView.SetMinimumHeight(0);
        middleView.SetMinimumWidth(0);
        middleView.SetElevation(1);
    });

    rootLayout.AddView(middleView);
    return rootLayout;
    }

return view;
}

Most of the code in my handler came from blog posts and reading other's work on getting a custom tabbar, so some of the nuances of what's happening in the handlers OnCreateView() are beyond me, but no matter what I tweak it doesn't seem to change the Android appearance.

What's the code of ArtemisBar? Could you please post more code snippets or a basic demo here so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?
